# Using JSon UTF8 Encode , with Google Translate, at PHP, it doesn't recognize the special characters.

Tags: php, json, utf-8, echo

I took an Alfred workflow called Google Translation, I edited and added some scripts. But when I translated from Portuguese or French into English - the strange characters appeared: pão --> paÌo.

I have edited the PHP file. I made many searches here at StackOverFlow about adding the support for the extra and special languages of all the languages - Latin, Cyrillic and other - UTF8. I tried all the ways as I could, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

function googleTranslate($request, $sourceLanguage, $targetLanguage)
{
    $url = 'http://translate.google.com.br/translate_a/t?client=p&text='.urlencode($request).'&hl=pt-BR&lr=lang_pt'.$sourceLanguage.'&tl='.$targetLanguage.'&multires=1&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1';

    $defaults = array(                                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,                 CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => true
    );

    $ch  = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $defaults);
    $out = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $result = '<?xml version="1.0"?><items>';

    $json = json_decode(utf8_encode($out));
    if (isset($json->dict)) {
        $googleResults = $json->dict[0]->entry;
        if (is_array($googleResults)) {
            foreach ($googleResults as $translatedData) {
                $result .= '<item uid="mtranslate" arg="'.$translatedData->word.'">';
                $result .= '<title>'.$translatedData->word.'</title>';
                $result .= '<subtitle>'.implode(', ', $translatedData->reverse_translation).'</subtitle>';
                $result .= '<icon>'.$targetLanguage.'.png</icon>';
                $result .= '</item>';
            }
        }
    } elseif (isset($json->sentences)) {
        foreach ($json->sentences as $sentence) {
            $result .= '<item uid="mtranslate" arg="'.$sentence->trans.'">';
            $result .= '<title>'.$sentence->trans.'</title>';
            $result .= '<subtitle>'.$sentence->orig.'</subtitle>';
            $result .= '<icon>'.$targetLanguage.'.png</icon>';
            $result .= '</item>';
        }
    } else {
        $result .= '<item uid="mtranslate">';
        $result .= '<title>No results found</title>';
        $result .= '</item>';
    }

    $result .= '</items>';
    echo $result;
}

// googleTranslate('Wohnmobil', 'de', 'en’, ‘pt’, ‘fr’);

?>
```

I also tried to add the "echo" PHP scripts to the at Alfred app's script editor (Mac app).

Comment: Why are you `utf8_encode`ing the result? It's entirely pointless and likely the source of your problem. See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Answer (score 2):

**json_decode**

you can use `json_decode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` on **php 5.4.0**

For **PHP 5.3** users  you can use this function for **UTF-8**

```
function my_json_encode($arr)
{
    //convmap since 0x80 char codes so it takes all multibyte codes (above ASCII 127). So such characters are being "hidden" from normal json_encoding
   array_walk_recursive($arr, function (&$item, $key) { if (is_string($item)) $item = mb_encode_numericentity($item, array (0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8'); });
   return mb_decode_numericentity(json_encode($arr), array (0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8');

 }
```

EX:

**my_json_encode($newArray**